# Unresponsive computer when left running some engineering simulations overnight

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, syslog, dmesg, responsiveness

This is the third time this has happened in last 4-5 months (16.04 as well as now 18.04 LTS). I run some engineering simulations on my Ubuntu machine and normally everything would be alright. Occasionally when I'm running these simulations and leave my PC on for over 2-3 days without interacting with it, this happens.

The machine is unresponsive to keyboard or mouse clicks. Earlier I thought it was the system that was suspended but it looks like it doesn't respond to mouse clicks or keyboard keys (realised this from the numlock LED behaviour). So I had to do hard reset. Why does this happen? Any clues? Where do I look?

I ran `tail -500 /var/log/syslog` to notice nothing unusual but the log apparently has entries only for the day (from 00:05 onward). Relevant entries here:

```
Sep 25 02:46:08 mae-hen-8163-db org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2028]: GetDntDataTotal sql exec success
Sep 25 02:46:08 mae-hen-8163-db org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2028]: GetDntDataQueue sql exec success
Sep 25 02:46:14 mae-hen-8163-db org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2028]: SchedulePriorTracktype called
Sep 25 02:46:14 mae-hen-8163-db org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2028]: GetDntDataPriorQueue sql exec success
Sep 25 02:46:47 mae-hen-8163-db org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2028]: SchedulePriorTracktype called
Sep 25 02:46:47 mae-hen-8163-db org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2028]: GetDntDataPriorQueue sql exec success
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Sep 25 10:29:23 mae-hen-8163-db systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
Sep 25 10:29:23 mae-hen-8163-db systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
Sep 25 10:29:23 mae-hen-8163-db systemd-modules-load[354]: Inserted module 'lp'
Sep 25 10:29:23 mae-hen-8163-db systemd-modules-load[354]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Sep 25 10:29:23 mae-hen-8163-db systemd-modules-load[354]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Sep 25 10:29:23 mae-hen-8163-db systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
Sep 25 10:29:23 mae-hen-8163-db systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
Sep 25 10:29:23 mae-hen-8163-db systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
    ......Some entries...
Sep 25 10:29:23 mae-hen-8163-db systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Sep 25 10:29:23 mae-hen-8163-db kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-34-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-047) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-34.37-generic 4.15.18)
```

The relevant line is the one with the zeros. That's when I did a hard reset and the boot sequence followed. There's a gap after 2:46 until the hard reset. What does that indicate?

I also checked with `sudo dmesg --ctime` to get following output (I do not understand any of it):

```
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] efifb: scrolling: redraw
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] intel_idle: MWAIT substates: 0x142120
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] intel_idle: v0.4.1 model 0x5E
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] intel_idle: lapic_timer_reliable_states 0xffffffff
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] (NULL device *): hwmon_device_register() is deprecated. Please convert the driver to use hwmon_device_register_with_info().
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ00] (28 C)
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] thermal LNXTHERM:01: registered as thermal_zone1
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (30 C)
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] 00:01: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] serial 0000:00:16.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] 0000:00:16.3: ttyS4 at I/O 0xf0a0 (irq = 20, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] tpm_tis MSFT0101:00: 2.0 TPM (device-id 0xFE, rev-id 4)
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:38 2018] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:39 2018] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:39 2018] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:39 2018] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:39 2018] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:39 2018] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:40 2018] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:41 2018] tpm tpm0: TPM self test failed
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:41 2018] loop: module loaded
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:41 2018] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:41 2018] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:41 2018] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[Tue Sep 25 10:28:41 2018] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
```

Is the above log relevant? Does it say something? Can someone please help me find a permanent solution to this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are there external USB hard drives connected to the PC? There are some known issue with the power management. When the problem occurs again try to reach the PC via network (`ping`, `ssh`). Try also to disable all power management options.

Comment: @SimonSudler Sorry for responding too late. I didn't realise question received a comment. No there aren't any connected USBs when this happens. However, now that you mention it, I did have a notification of USB having removed after I restarted the machine. I thought that was weird since no USBs were in use. This might be a clue. What should I do to check and correct this?